# Correct way to check if a word is the last

Tags: c#

I have a string with some text, for example:

```
var txt = "this is an example";
```

How can I check if a given word is the last ? Currently I am checking with `try catch`

```
try 
  {
     var index = txt.indexOf(word);
     var dummy = txt[index + word.Length-1];
  }

catch(IndexOutOfRangeException ex) {
        // do work
  }
```

Comment: You could just check against `txt.Length`. Using `try catch` is definitely not a good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var txt = "this is an example";
if (txt.Split (new []{ ' ' }).LastOrDefault ().Equals (word)) {
   // equals
}
```

I assume, that *word* is not empty.
And your method, a little bit improved:

```
if (txt.LastIndexOf(word) == txt.Length - word.Length) {
  // equals         
}
```

Comment: warning: you can get an NPE if txt is empty with LastOrDefault